# methods for comparing strings with numbers

Tags: string

I have been doing some string problems.
The problem now is to check if a  ip is valid or not.
for example 255.6.13.4.
The ip is stored in a string.Now i have to check whether the numbers lie between 0 to 255.
Is there any way to split the ip and compare with numbers or any other way around it.
thanks in advance

Comment: Use a [regular expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`stringstreams`**](https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [**`std::getline()`**](https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), it has a delimiter parameter.

[**Link to live sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ovKtztcXzXlzWjUU)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "123.231.0.43";

    std::stringstream test(str);
    std::string temp;
    int temp_int;
    std::vector<int> addr_elements; //int vector, you can use a string vector if you prefer

    while (std::getline(test, temp, '.')) //split by delimiter '.'
    {   

        std::stringstream ssint(temp);
        ssint >> temp_int;     //string to int
        addr_elements.push_back(temp_int); //now you have a vector of integers
    }

    for(int i : addr_elements){ //test print the vector
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: @rishi_harshan Glad to help.